# Cartoon with a boy in an ant's kingdom

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have very vivid memories of an old movie- cartoon from when I was I child.

It was about a kid who was made small and he was able to go to an ant kingdom. This happened in a living room, they had a thick and big haired carpet where he would get lost when he got smaller, then there was something with a vacuum cleaner. Some scenes are filmed, some are cartoon, like in the ant's kingdom.

It's around 20-25 years ago. At that time it looked like it was a new movie. Maybe even 30 years ago, if it took time to get on screen in my country.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the 2006 film [_The Ant Bully_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429589/) but I believe that is all cartoon.

Comment: And of course there's also _Honey, I Shrunk the Kids_ but if I remember correctly that is all live action. [Relevant scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rcf89x12fdU).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't see anything indicating there are live-action parts, but it is also probably too recent, only 13 years old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [*Dot and Keeto*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090960/) (1986)

> Dot, an Australian girl, seeks the magical green root that will give her the ability to talk to animals. She eats a red root by mistake, and is shrunk to the size of an ant. With the help of her friends Keeto the mosquito and Butterwalk the caterpillar, she searches for the green root that will restore her size. But she must find it before sundown, or she will shrink even smaller.

The full movie is available on YouTube:

There is a hoovering scene around 13 minutes and the ant scene around 34 minutes.

---

Found with the Google query `cartoon boy shrunk ants -"ant bully" -"shrunk the kids"` just to remove the most popular results.

Comment: Doesn't the question say that its about a BOY instead of a girl?

Comment: @BellaSwan it does but it matches everything else. You’d be surprised how mixed up your memory can make things so it’s worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for it for years :)

Comment: In my memory it's a boy :D

Comment: But now that I see it I remember more